# caching strategy in onprem server mule 4

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mulesoft, mule4

I've implemented caching strategy in mule 4 and it's working fine in the local anypoint but after deployment on windows and linux on-premise server it's not working. It's always executing the flow inside caching block.

Do i need some setting on onprem server to work it?

```
     <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="Caching_Strategy_Token" doc:name="Caching Strategy" doc:id="1a901405-84c0-456a-ba66-ef2a16d98b8e" keyGenerationExpression="#vars.userName">
     <os:private-object-store entryTtl="1000" entryTtlUnit="MINUTES" expirationInterval="60" maxEntries="60"/>
     </ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

Answer (score 0):

The key generation expression is not a correct expression, so it is being interpreted as a literal string. The expression has to be between brackets (`#[...]`).

Example:

```
keyGenerationExpression="#[vars.userName]"
```

But that should cause it to always cache, so probably there is something else.

Have you check if the value of vars.userName is different each time?

Comment: yes most of the time userName is same as per the api